# Left-hand side of assignment expression cannot be a constant or a read-only property in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Here's how my code looks like

```
this.timezones = moment.tz.names();
for(let timezone in this.timezones) {
  this.timezones[timezone] = this.timezones[timezone] +' '+ moment.tz(this.timezones[timezone]).format('Z z');
}
```

I am getting the above mentioned error in line present inside for loop, I didn't get this error until i upgraded to angular2.1

is there any other way to access the elements of timezones variable to make it writable as well?

Comment: Where is `timezones`? The `let timezones` seems to be something else because it seems to be in the same method as the `for` loop code.

Comment: timezones is class property.. and is accessed like this.timezones

Comment: It would be great if you could update your question to make the central parts of your question clear ;-)

Comment: Why are you trying to modify moment's list of timezone names? Make your own modified list. What is the declaration of `this.timezones`, by the way?

Comment: I am modifying it because i want to show it in that format, and declaration is like

timezones :String;

Answer (score 0):

as per [docs of moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/getting-zone-names/)

```
moment.tz.names(); // String[]
```

gives string array.

now,

```
this.timezones[timezone] is undefined.
```